# How to get partial properties from JSON returned from HttpClient fast?

Tags: c#, json, .net, parsing, dotnet-httpclient

I have a JSON snippet [here](https://jsonblob.com/5539ad94-d97b-11eb-b59a-d7d5ec8a49c8) taken from `HttpClient` class below in a C# .NET 5 program.

Simplified JSON:

```json
{
    "Restaurants":
    [
        {
            "Id": 138898,
            "Name": "Willesborough Cafe",
            "Rating": {
                "Count": 76,
                "Average": 5.92,
                "StarRating": 5.92
            },
            "CuisineTypes": [
                {
                    "Id": 92,
                    "IsTopCuisine": false,
                    "Name": "Breakfast",
                    "SeoName": "breakfast"
                }, {
                    "Id": 106,
                    "IsTopCuisine": true,
                    "Name": "British",
                    "SeoName": "british"
                }
            ],
            "Cuisines": [
                {
                    "Name": "Breakfast",
                    "SeoName": "breakfast"
                }, {
                    "Name": "British",
                    "SeoName": "british"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Current code:

```
            dynamic result =
                await _httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<dynamic>(url);
            // dynamic result2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(result); // slow
            dynamic result2 = JObject.Parse(result); // slow
```

I am interested to get the info from each restaurant below from the `Restaurants` array:

1. Name
2. Rating
3. CusineType

I use `dynamic` as I do not need to create multiple classes based on the JSON structure & I do not need to change my class if the JSON structure changes.

I have tried `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` & `JObject.Parse`.

However, the Visual Studio debugging stuck at either of the method for a very long period

What is the recommended method to get partial properties from a huge JSON response?

Thanks

Comment: If the helper methods aren't sufficient for you, then the only other option would be to use the `JsonReader` to manually read through the JSON and extract the bits you want, while skipping the others and not dedicating extra processing time to them. It's possible that this won't be fast enough for your needs either, but that's the fastest way to do it.

Comment: It shouldn't be all that slow, maybe the delay is because it's waiting for the request result.

Comment: @anastaciu, I could see the `result` value instantly after `_httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync` runs. Why is it waiting for request while I could see the value?

Comment: @Llama, would you be kind enough to provide an example to my problem as a solution?

Comment: @Unknown I dind't know that.

Comment: Hold up: `GetFromJsonAsync` is already returning a deserialized object in your example. Why are you then trying to parse it?

Comment: Also, parsing your entire JSON document with `JObject.Parse` took an average of 4.494ms (i.e. a little bit faster than 1/200th of a second) in my tests. I've also tested `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);` and it is also a little faster than 1/200th of a second.

Comment: @Llama, how do I get the Name, Rating, CusineType from the `dynamic` object after I run `GetFromJsonAsync`?

Comment: Well, I would personally opt to deserialize it to classes specially crafted to hold the JSON data. JSON.NET just deserializes to `JObject` or `JArray` (depending on the source data) under the hood when you use `dynamic`.

Comment: @Llama, if I use the classes option, do I need to keep changing the classes whenever the JSON structure changes?

Comment: You would, yes. But you would have to update your code anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a class with named properties

```
    class Restaurant
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Rating Rating { get; set; }

    public List<CuisineType> CuisineTypes { get; set; }
}

class Rating
{
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public decimal Average { get; set; }
    public decimal StarRating { get; set; }
}

class CuisineType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsTopCuisine { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SeoName { get; set; }
}
```

and deserialize json to instance of ***Restaurant*** then you have a type you need. That's it.
You need to have a class contains list of Restaurant, because you must have a property equal name with your json object

```
class RestaurantList { public List<Restaurant> Restaurants {get; set;} }
```

Now you need a code to bind section of json to object

```
var restaurants = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RestaurantList>(result);
```

Comment: Can you provide example how to deserialize with your code? Will other properties in JSON be discarded during deserialization?

Comment: You need to have a class contains list of Restaurant, because you must have a property equal name with your json object
class RestaurantList {
    public List<Restaurant> Restaurants {get; set;}
}
Now you need a code to bind section of json to object

var restaurants = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RestaurantList>(result);